# 2D image processing algorithm to process a set of images and build a big image

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I was wondering if there was any algorithm where you provide a set of images so it build one big image out of them? The set of images can have overlapping pixels.

Thus, an algorithm which detects the corners of the set image and glues it to the big image ignoring the pixels which are already drawn in the big image.

I hope my explanation was not that bad.

Comment: take a look at Hugin. it is a set of command line tools that implements those algorithms and does exactly what you want. its also open source, so if you really wanted to implement it yourself, the code is available.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I'm looking for!